# Build Mint.com like data pulling system from financial accounts

Tags: portfolio

Mint.com, during registration, takes financial information from the user and fetches the data from those financial accounts. For my portfolio website, I would like to build Mint.com like data pulling system that can get me their stocks and funds details. What would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Look at Yodlee. Mint used to use Yodlee before their acquisition by Intuit. Also, Personalcapital, FutureAdvisor use Yodlee to get financial transaction information.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to do this one at a time with each company.  Look first if there's an API avail thats the easiest.  If not then you might have to scrape the information, it'll be a tough as there's so many financial institutions and any change on their side could break your downloading process.